# Отсортировать несвязанные строки

Tags: excel

[image: Таблица excel]
Имеется такая таблица excel. Необходимо отсортировать данные(белые поля) в случайном порядке в несвязанных строках.Как это можно сделать?

Имеется опыт сортировки при помощи

```
=CЛЧИС()
```

но как быть когда строки не связаны? 
Неужели придется **перекопировать** данные на отдельный лист, затем добавить столбец с

```
=СЛЧИС()
```

а затем как следует их сортирнуть? :]

Есть ли методы получше, чем этот сферический конь в вакууме?

Спасибо, камрады, за наставление на путь истинный!

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант решения без макросов**, только используя формулы `Excel`, сортировку по нескольким столбцам и разделение листа `Исходной таблицы` на листы:

`Данные` - содержит данные с дополнительными столбцами, имеющими формулу, для сортировки;

`Форму` - отображает данных в требуемом формате случайным образом.

По шагам:

1. Имеем лист `Исходная таблица`

[image: 1]

2. Создаем лист `Данные`, перед столбцами, которые необходимо сортировать в случайном порядке, вставляем новые столбцы с функциями `СЛЧИСЛ()`.

[image: 2]

На примере добавленные столбцы: `Сл Наименование товара`, `Сл Параметр 2`.

3. Для сортировки по нескольким столбцам используем `Данные / Сортировка`. В примере столбцы: `Сл Наименование товара`, `Сл Параметр 2`.

Примечание: при выборе `ОК` произойдет сортировка и сразу же пересчет функции `СЛЧИСЛ()`.

[image: 3]

4. Для отображения данных в требуемом формате создаем лист `Форма`.

[image: 4]

5. Для отображения значений в полях используем формулу для первой строки `=ИНДЕКС(Данные!$A$1:$F$6;СТРОКА();3)`, которая ссылается на вторую строку третьего столбца листа `Данные`. Для корректного отображения третьей и следующих строк формула с учетом смещения строк - `=ИНДЕКС(Данные!$A$1:$F$6;СТРОКА()/2+1;3)`

[image: 5]

6. Все это работает следующим образом: функция СЛЧИСЛ() ячейкам присваивает случайное значение, при применении `Сортировки` на листе `Данные` происходит изменение порядка значений в ячейках, результат сортировки по ссылкам отображается на листе `Форма`.
7. При необходимости ячейки с листа `Форма` копируются и значения вставляются на другой лист.

**Вариант решения с использованием макросов.** Основная идея: значения ячеек необходимые для сортировки копируем в исходный массив, который сортируется случайным образом (получаем результирующий массив) и далее записываем в ячейки таблицы.

По шагам:

1. Код макроса

   ```
   Option Explicit '  включаем явное объявления всех переменных
   Option Base 1   ' объявляем нижнюю границу по умолчанию для индексов массивов
   ' основная идея: значения ячеек необходимые для сортировки копируем в исходный массив,
   ' который сортируется случайным образом (получаем результирующий массив) и далее
   ' записываем в ячейки таблицы
   Sub RandomOrderTable()
   Dim sSrtblClmn As String    ' строка содержащая номер столбцов, в которых будет производиться сортировка ячеек
   Dim aSrtblClmn() As String  ' массив для хранения номеров столбцов, в которых будет производится сортировка ячеек
   Dim aRw() As Variant        ' исходный массив со значениями ячеек таблицы
   Dim aRndRw() As Variant     ' результирующий массив со значениями элементов aRw отсортированных случайным образом
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim k As Integer
   Dim l As Integer            ' индекс исходного массива (количества ячеек), который будет подвергнут сортировке
   Dim iLstRw As Integer       ' количество строк исходной таблицы
   Dim iClrIndx As Integer     ' значение индекса цвет заливки для строк не участвующих в сортировке

   iLstRw = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row     ' определили количесвто строк исходной таблицы

   sSrtblClmn = "2;4"
   aSrtblClmn = Split(sSrtblClmn, ";")

   iClrIndx = Cells(2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex      ' определили индекс цвета ячейки без заливки
   ' цикл перебора столбцов, которые будут копироваться в массив
   For i = LBound(aSrtblClmn) To UBound(aSrtblClmn)
       l = 1
       ' цикл перебора строк, которые будут копироваться в массив
       For k = 1 To iLstRw
           ' проверяем фон ячейки, если заливки нет, то копируем значение ячейки в исходный массив
           If Cells(k, Int(aSrtblClmn(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = iClrIndx Then
               ' переопределяем массив и заносим значение ячейки в массив
               ReDim Preserve aRw(l)
               aRw(l) = Cells(k, Int(aSrtblClmn(i))).Value
               l = l + 1
           End If
       Next k
       ' сортируем массив случайным образом и сохраняем результат в результирующем массиве
       aRndRw = SortRndArray(aRw)

       l = 1
       ' записываем значения результирующего массива в ячейки
       For k = 1 To iLstRw
           If Cells(k, Int(aSrtblClmn(i))).Interior.ColorIndex = iClrIndx Then
               Cells(k, Int(aSrtblClmn(i))).Value = aRndRw(l)
               l = l + 1
           End If
       Next k
   Next i
   End Sub

   ' функция случайной сортировки взята по ссылке http://hav.su/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64:-2&catid=35:calc
   Function SortRndArray(A As Variant) As Variant
     'B - массив-результат
     Dim B As Variant
     'случайный индекс элемента массива
     Dim MyRndValue As Byte
     Dim i As Integer
     'Max_i - максимальное количество элементов
     Dim Max_i As Integer
     Max_i = UBound(A, 1)
     ReDim B(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)) As Variant
     'заполнение выходного массива B
     'в произвольном порядке выбирая их из A
     For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
       'определение номера элемента из A
       MyRndValue = Int((Max_i * Rnd) + 1)
       'занесение этого элемента в выходной массив
       B(i) = A(MyRndValue)
       'замещение выбранного элемента из A последним элементом из A
       A(MyRndValue) = A(Max_i)
       'понижение верхней границы массива
       'т.о. "уменьшаем" размер массива на один элемент
       Max_i = Max_i - 1 
     Next i
     'возвращаем массив значений B
     SortRndArray = B
   End Function
   ```
2. Копируем код макроса в таблицу `Excel` (`Разработчик - Vsual Basic`);
3. Исходная таблица:

[image: 23]

4. Запускаем макрос (`Alt+F8`)

[image: 24]

5. Получаем результат:

[image: 25]